# How to put the link to the post in the summary image using javascript in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger

I found this template on the internet, it is perfect for my purpose.
 
But there is only one problem, the image in the summary does not link to the post, I've identified the script, but I do not know the blogger's api and I do not know much about javascript, so I can not get the image to link to the post.

[BLOG PREVIEW (testenextdark.blogspot.com)](https://testenextdark.blogspot.com/)
[TEMPLATE CODE (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/uwMSEWXS)

```
//<![CDATA[

function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}

//]]>
```

Comment: do you want to make image as a link to drive you to post ?

Comment: yes  want to make image as a link to drive to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little change on `createSummaryAndThumb` function to get post link and wrap `<img>` tag inside `<a>` tag . your code should be like that :

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    var link = div.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.post-title a').getAttribute('href');
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="'+link+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```